# Discard changes made in a Gridcontrol when a user clicks the "Cancel" button and exit

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have 2 Forms. The First forms is for creating/updating a person and has a button to a 2nd form which holds information to a person's children using a DevExpress GridControl.

I let the user an option to CRUD the children form even when he just created a new person (Maybe a design failure by me but that's another matter). When they finish filling the children details they can hit the "save" or "cancel and exit" buttons. If they hit "cancel.." I need the underlying children DataTable to revert back to the way it was before. I tried the CancelEdit() method of BindingSource without success. I then tried to do the next thing:

```
void CancelBtn_Click(Object sender,EventArgs e) 
{
         DataTable dt = (DataTable)BindingSource.DataSouce as DataTable;
         dt.RejectChanges();
}
```

Which doesn't work if first time you open and CRUD the children grid and hit **save** and on the second time you open do some other stuff and hit **cancel** it will revert back your first save operations too cause I update the database only when the user finish with creating the person completely and hit "save" on the person form and not in between children form updates.

I'm taking care of the relation manually so I have to have person row and id created first and only then I save the children to database.

Am I doing it all wrong ?

Comment: are you creating the `dt` variable every time when the user click on the button, if so try to use a single variable you always refer to.

Comment: no, I create the dt once on the main form (person) and pass it around via a BindingSource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use another `DataTable` variable to hold values for your second form and use this variable as `GridControl.DataSource` instead of `BindingSource`. When the user clicks <kbd>Save</kbd> button you need to update your details table.

Here is example:

**0. Create `DataTable` for your second form:**

```
var secondFormTable = new DataTable();

foreach (DataColumn column in detailsTable.Columns)
    secondFormTable.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, column.DataType);

secondFormTable.Columns.Add("DetailsRow", typeof(DataRow));

foreach (var detailsRow in detailsTable.Select("Some filter to get child rows"))
{
    var secondFormRow = secondFormTable.Rows.Add(detailsRow.ItemArray);
    secondFormRow["DetailsRow"] = detailsRow;
}

secondFormTable.AcceptChanges();

secondFormGridControl.DataSource = secondFormTable;
```

And when the user clicks <kbd>Save</kbd> button you need to update your details table.

**1. Update details table from `secondFormTable`:**

```
void SaveBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var secondFormTable = (DataTable)secondFormGridControl.DataSouce;

    foreach (DataRow secondFormRow in secondFormTable.Rows)
        switch (secondFormRow.RowState)
        {
            case DataRowState.Added:
            case DataRowState.Modified:
                DataRow detailsRow;

                if (secondFormRow.RowState == DataRowState.Added)
                {
                    detailsRow = detailsTable.NewRow();
                    detailsTable.Rows.Add(detailsRow);
                }
                else
                    detailsRow = (DataRow)secondFormRow["DetailsRow"];

                foreach (DataColumn column in detailsTable.Columns)
                    detailsRow[column] = secondFormRow[column.ColumnName];
                break;

            case DataRowState.Deleted:
                ((DataRow)secondFormRow["DetailsRow", DataRowVersion.Original]).Delete();
                break;
        }
}
```

Comment: If I do that then I reset the rows state (Modified,Deleted etc..) and then I can't save it on my person main save.

Comment: @yossielimelech You can reject changes in each row separately in your second form. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Hi sorry but I don't see how that is helpful to me. In my code in personForm I have a main_save() method that saves children rows by their rowstate. (if rowstate == modified then update command is built etc.) I need to be able to save changes to children table and sync it with my gridcontrol until I hit that main_save() method.

Comment: @yossielimelech So, you need to use another `DataTable` variable instead of `BindingSource`. Take a look at my updated answer.